# App Crash instantly without exception or log (seems like xamarin/mono bug)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

It's a weird situation here :) , I have implemented this code in my fragment to scan `TCP Ports` in `multithread environment` , it `crash when debugging` , and sometimes `crash in release mode` too with thoose messages :

`E/art     (12972): Nested signal detected - original signal being reported`

`F/art     (12972): art/runtime/fault_handler.cc:117] Check failed: !initialized_`

> tried to set Target `Android to 23` that didn’t work.
>
> tried running `adb shell setprop debug.mono.env
>   MONO_DEBUG=soft-breakpoints` that didn’t work.
>
> tried to compile using different `Android API's Versions`

**ANY IDEA WHY IS THIS HAPPENING ??**

> > HERE IS MY CODE:

```
    public void start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RunScanTcp());
            //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunScanTcp);
            //Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunScanTcp));
            //thread.Start();
        }
    }


    public void RunScanTcp()
    {
        while (abort != true)
        {
                port = port + 1;
                Log.Info("PORT SCANNER", port.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class PortList
    {
        private int start;
        private int stop;
        private int ports;
        private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

        public PortList(int starts, int stops)
        {
            start = starts;
            stop = stops;
            ports = start;
        }

        public bool MorePorts()
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                return (stop - ports) >= 0;
            }
        }

        public int NextPort()
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (MorePorts())
                {
                    return ports++;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Im compiling using :

`Android Version (Android 7.1 Nougat)`

Minimum Android Version :

`Android 4.1 (API Level 16 - Jelly Bean)`

Target Android Version:

`Compile Using SDK Version`

**UPDATE :**

After `Visual Studio Update 15.2 (26430.12)` , and `Xamarin 4.5.0.476` - `30/05/2017`(dd/mm/yyyy) the application `crashed` while is `connected to debugger` too...

> Here is the debugger output :

```
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=428 1
referenceTable GSUB length=2302 1
referenceTable GPOS length=43252 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=808 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=49128 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=808 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47320 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
05-31 04:31:51.590 F/art     (17427): art/runtime/fault_handler.cc:117] Check failed: !initialized_
```

**Thank's All of you ...**

Comment: Have you tried to check "arm64-v8a" in the Advanced Tab of Android Build Options?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT yes , i tried it , its the same situation again ....

Comment: Did you enable proguard for your release build?

Comment: @HarisQureshi , i have tried with proguard enabled and disabled , its the same thing , it still crash ...

Comment: You can add log messages to see which line causes your app to crash. That might give you some more clues.

Comment: @daramasala , with what tool can make this ?

Comment: @EAKTEAM `Console.WriteLine()`

Comment: But i dont know which line is causing the error , and what to write in the writeline ? :D :D

Comment: You could make a very small 'hello world' type app and push it over as a sort of general test to see if its something to do with your build environment or something about this app specifically.

Comment: @ashbygeek , i have tried that too ... It still crash... I dont understand this...

Comment: @EAKTEAM Weird. That does sound like some sort of build environment problem. Have you tried restarting the computer and the phone?

Comment: @ashbygeek , yes this is so weird .. Im going crazy of that and my app depend on it , cant move forward and leave this for the moment as is... :D , i have tried everything , restarting phone , another phone , computer , updating to the last version of vs and xamarin too :D

Comment: @EAKTEAM I haven't actually worked with Xamarin myself so I'm afraid I can't be much more help. I took a look at it because I've used Unity to make a phone app and I've worked with adb a bit, but you're passed my experience level. My last advice is that it might be good to update your question with the fact that you've tried reboots and multiple computers and phones and pushing a simpler app. Good luck!

Comment: @ashbygeek , thank you anyway and yes i accept your advice. I will update it later bcos im in phone right now. Thanks

Comment: @EAKTEAM What happend, when you try to run app without any code (starter template)?

Comment: @SamuelTulach , this app have many fragments , when i remove this fragment from the app , it work correctly ... (or when i disable button click event , that fire those method ) it works ok ... i have tried many many ways to find what cause this weird error but still nothing ... Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What if you create only 1 task instead of 50 ? Besides, how about adding a Thread.Sleep() in the loop of your task ?

Comment: have you checked the catlog? There it must tell you the exception and crash motive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in `xamarin.android platform` because after last update `6/9/2017` `Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.13)` it dont crash anymore ... anyway thanks for your time .. This bug happens when tried to create (n) number of threads/task ...

Answer (score 3):

As you described it is working without that part of your code ... so the error must be somewhere in your code.

let's look at it.

```
public void start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => RunScanTcp());
    }
}


public void RunScanTcp()
{
    while (abort != true)
    {
            port = port + 1;
            Log.Info("PORT SCANNER", port.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the `start` method you start 50 tasks - and not `await`ing any of them - which means, that possibly all tasks run in parallel (at least **definitely** some tasks try to access `port` at the same time).

What those tasks execute is a method that accesses `port` which must be a field of the containing class.

Accessing a shared field from multiple tasks / threads is never a good idea without a lock.

Try using the following code instead (if you really need the parallel tasks for some reason).

```
public class YourClass
{

    private bool abort;
    private int port;
    private object portLock = new object();

    public void start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RunScanTcp());
        }
    }


    public void RunScanTcp()
    {
        while (abort != true && this.port < int.MaxValue)
        {
            lock (this.portLock) {
                port = port + 1;
                Log.Info("PORT SCANNER", port.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Possibly a better approach is to only use one task and somewhere `await` it.

```
public class YourClass
{

    private bool abort;
    private int port;
    private object portLock = new object();

    public Task start()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => RunScanTcp());
    }


    public void RunScanTcp()
    {
        lock (this.portLock) {
            while (abort != true && this.port < int.MaxValue)
            {
                port = port + 1;
                Log.Info("PORT SCANNER", port.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If that solves your current problem you might want to add another question about how to properly solve what you're actually trying to solve (since your current code basically just increments the `port` until it is aborted or the app crashes (since it counted above the `Int32` MaxValue)

Comment: In fact in using lock in the `portlist class` (see above)... the problem seems to be in xamarin.android platforms because after last update 6/9/2017 `Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.13)` it dont crash anymore ... anyway thanks for your time , and that code was just for demostration im not increment just the port number

Answer (score 2):

So I came across an issue just like that with Xamarin and VS. it turns out that not all error are logged into the VS debugging console, but they are in the device log. What I had to do that time was to go and use the emulator on my machine and run it while having the device log ON. and stopped the logging right after the crash. In that log it was clear what the issue was (which in my case was a misconfigured permission). Hope that helps.

Comment: i didn't try using emulator , i will try , hope to work in this way ...

Comment: it don't helped me ... :(

Comment: I really didn't meant to say to use the emulator, but rather using the "Device log" which is different from the VS debug console. That thing logs everything that happens in the android machine (with clear exceptions). You open it from the toolbar next to the manage android devices button.

Comment: It says same exception in logcat too

Answer (score 0):

For apk file to be working on other devices than connected to USB debugging, You need to publish signed APK file and distribute it, Check below link:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/